# Reasoning about prime counting and the twin prime conjecture

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, twin-primes

I've been thinking the primorial for say the $i$th prime $p_i$and the equations for counting the number of elements in the reduced residue system for this primorial and counting the number of elements of the form $6x-1$ that have a sister element of $6x-1+2$

Let $R$ = the set of elements of the reduced residue system for $p_i\#$

Let $T$ = the set of elements of the reduced residue system of form $6x-1$ where $(6x-1)+2$ is also an element of $R$.

Let $[R]$ = the number of elements of $R$ and $[T]$ = the number of elements of $T$

I know that these equations are well known:

- $|R|= (p_i-1)\cdot(p_{i-1}-1)\cdot(p_{i-2}-1)\cdot\,\dots\, \cdot(3-1)$
- $|T|= (p_i-2)\cdot(p_{i-1}-2)\cdot(p_{i-2}-2)\cdot\,\dots\, \cdot(5-2)$

Here are my questions:

- If we define $S$ as the number of elements that do not have a twin element, is it correct that:  $|S| = |R| - 2\cdot|T|$
- If $\pi(x)$ is the prime counting function.  Is it correct that the twin prime conjecture would be proved if it turned out that:

$$\pi(p_i\#) > |S| + \dfrac{1}{2}|T|$$

- Assuming that my reasoning is correct, how close have folks gotten to proving this comparison?  Is there any paper that you can cite about the twin prime conjecture?

Thanks,

-Larry

---

Edit: I did some calculations and here's what I found:

- For $p_i = 5$, $\pi(p_i\#) - |S| + \dfrac{1}{2}|T| = 4.5$
- For $p_i = 7$, $\pi(p_i\#) - |S| + \dfrac{1}{2}|T| = 16.5$
- For $p_i = 11$, $\pi(p_i\#) - |S| + \dfrac{1}{2}|T| = 61.5$

But then:

- For $p_i = 13$, $\pi(p_i\#) - |S| + \dfrac{1}{2}|T| = -290.5$
- For $p_i = 17$, $\pi(p_i\#) - |S| + \dfrac{1}{2}|T| = -16422.5$

---

Edit: Can anyone prove that if $p_i > 11$, then:

$$\pi(p_i\#) < |S| + \dfrac{1}{2}|T|$$

Comment: Explain what you mean by "reduced residue system for this primorial".

Comment: Sorry if my terminology is incorrect.  I'm taking this from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_residue_system).  So, for $p_3\# = 5\# = 30$, I mean the set relatively prime to $30$ which is $\left\{1,7,11,13,17,19,23,29\right\}$  What would be a better way to state this?

Comment: Larry, you said it right. @gnasher729: you only had to google "reduced residue system".